# How to compile and run c++ programs with sublime text 3?

Tags: c++, compilation, sublimetext3

I want to compile and run a c++ program in cmd every time I hit CTRL+B in Sublime Text 3. Also I need to keep the window alive after the program is fully executed. I particularly love the build system which code-block uses. Can I implement the same system in Sublime?

So far, I have following build system:

```
{
"cmd": ["mingw32-g++", "-o", "$file_base_name", "$file"],
"path": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\",
"variants": [

    {   
        "cmd": ["start", "cmd", "/k", "$file_base_name"],
        "shell": true,
        "name": "Run"
    }
    ]
}
```

The only problem here is that I  have to compile first and then run it. I want to have it compiled and run in a single operation.

**Edit:**
I have solved this problem by the following build system:

```
{
"cmd": ["g++.exe", "-std=c++11", "-o", "$file_base_name", "$file", "&&", "start", "cmd", "/c", "$file_base_name & echo. & echo. & pause"],
"shell": true,
"selector": "source.c++"
}
```

Comment: You should pass `-Wall -Wextra -g` to `g++`. Than will save you hours of your time (by warning you against obvious mistakes)

Answer (score 2):

1. Sublime Text is a text editor wherein you can use different languages under the same hood.
2. Regarding your c++ program you have to install some packages for the version of c++ you are using. I recommend to watch some tutorials to get a step by step procedure and better understanding.

Answer (score 2):

```
{
"shell_cmd": "g++ -std=c++11 -Wall \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\" && start cmd /k \"$file_base_name\"",
"working_dir": "${file_path}",
"selector": "source.cpp, source.cxx, source.cc, source.c++"
}
```

go to Tools -> build system -> new build system -> Paste It -> save it as "C++", then close it. 
now save your C++/C code with .cpp extention (important .c extention is not supported) then to compile it go to tools -> build with Select "C++"
file download link:https://github.com/mahirx/configurations/blob/master/sublime_text/c_and_c%2B%2Bv2/C%2B%2B.sublime-build

please notify me if you found any mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Configure your editor to run [`make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) (or [`ninja`](https://ninja-build.org/) ...) for <kbd>CTRL B</kbd> and use a `Makefile`, a `build.ninja`, or some other **[build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool**. So you could add the appropriate rule (to your [`Makefile`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile) etc....) to run  something else.

<sup>(both [GNU `make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html) and [`ninja`](https://ninja-build.org/manual.html) have good documentation and tutorials, and you could ask questions about them on SO, with some [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))</sup>

[Source code editors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_editor) are tools to edit source code. Configure them to run the external programs (compilers, debuggers, your own thing, ... or  `make` or `ninja`) appropriately.

> The only problem here is that I have to compile first and then run it. I want to have it compiled and run in a single operation.

So build with a good enough build automation tool. Configure your editor to run `make`, and edit your `Makefile` to make "compile then run" the default target (and likewise with `ninja` and its `build.ninja` file). Remember that compilers like [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) (even started from IDEs) are command line programs (and your `mingw32-g++` is a [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler).

Take also the good habit to compile with all warnings and debug info, so  [pass](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `-Wall -Wextra -g` to your [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) that is your `mingw32-g++` (hence, edit appropriately your `Makefile` or `build.ninja` file).

<sup>In other words, an IDE - that is just a buzzword - is a source code editor suitably configured to run other programs. My preference is `emacs`</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the info. But I am not too experienced in this. Maybe you can build the build-system for me :)

Comment: No, you need to read a bit. However, I did post several `Makefile`-s examples on SO; using both `make` and `ninja` is easy, and both have good documentations and tutorials. You need to spend a few hours reading, and that will improve your practical knowledge (even for *future* project). So start writing your own `Makefile` or `build.ninja`, and ask questions about them. Likewise, reading documentation of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) is useful and not a waste of time.

Comment: Done! I have a perfect build now!

Comment: You really should spend more time reading about `make`, `ninja`, `g++`; and your build is still poor, not perfect! More generally, you should read more

Comment: Yeah it is not perfect. But it still solves my problem as of now. I will definitely spend more time on those topics. Thanks!